# ValueError using sklearn and pandas for decision trees?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I'm new to scikit learn and I just saw the documentation and a couple of other stackoverflow posts to build a decision tree.
I have a CSV data set with 16 attributes and 1 target label. How should I pass it into the decision tree classifier?
My current code looks like this:

```
import pandas
import sklearn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import tree

data = pandas.read_csv("yelp_atlanta_data_labelled.csv", sep=',')
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(data) 
Y = data['go']

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

When I run the code it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of labels=501 does not match number of samples=17
```

To give some context, my data set has 501 data points and 17 total columns. The `go` column is the target column with yes/no labels.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `TfidfVectorizer` cannot operate on a dataframe directly. It can only operate on a sequence of strings. Because you are passing a dataframe, it sees it as a sequence of columns and attempts to vectorize each column separately.

Try instead using:

```
X = vect.fit_transform(data['my_column_name'])
```

You may want to preprocess the dataframe to concatenate different columns prior to calling `vect.fit_transform`.